# Windows XP does not see my SD card

Tags: windows-xp, sd-card

I have an SD slot in my laptop.  However, when I pop in an SD card no drive appears in My Computer.

I've looked around in both BIOS and the Control Panel, and I can't seem to find any entries controlling whether the SD slot is enabled or not.

What am I missing?

Comment: what model is the laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go in to `device manager` and double check that you do not have any yellow triangles or disabled devices.

If you do, update the drivers for your card reader.

If you do not, try finding the card reader and disabling it then enabling as on my Realtek card reader, this usually does the job.

Also, if it still does not work, are you sure that your card is working?

Last thing to try is to go to `disk management` and make sure that the card reader has a drive letter assigned (when the card is in).

Comment: Thanks.  I believe my brain temporarily froze. Drivers, of course.  The only odd thing about the experience is that there were no indications in the Device Manager.  No yellow triangles whatsoever.